# View Image Full Screen like Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a feature within my app so that when the user taps on an image, the image is displayed "full screen". The behavior on tap should be to move the existing picture to full screen width so that none of the image is lost. My code currently moves the image to occupy the height of the phone and therefore crops the width.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
isFullScreen = FALSE;
tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imgToFullScreen:)];
tap.delegate = self;



_imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
[_imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
_imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
_imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mac4.png"];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapper = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imgToFullScreen:)];
tapper.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

[_imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapper];

[self.view addSubview:_imageView];
}

-(void)imgToFullScreen:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
if (!isFullScreen) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
        //save previous frame
        prevFrame = _imageView.frame;
        [_imageView setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        isFullScreen = TRUE;
    }];
    return;
}
else{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
        [_imageView setFrame:prevFrame];
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        isFullScreen = FALSE;
    }];
    return;
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I know that this following line of code doesn't allow the user to view the image full screen like Facebook:

```
[_imageView setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

So basically, when the user taps the image, I want the image to be viewed full screen while making sure none of the image is lost. Facebook is a perfect example for what I'm trying to go for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` instead of `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`. AspectFill will try to fill the entire imageView with the image, but `AspectFit` will make sure the entire image fits in the imageView.